# Monitoring HP Smartarray (cciss) with nagios

Tags: linux, hp, raid1, nagios

I'm trying to monitor an HP Smart Array controller using nagios. I have 4 disks on 2 RAID1 arrays, so 2 disks per RAID1.

I installed nrpe-server and nrpe-plugins and I'm using the almighty `check_raid` plugin, but it seems to only be seeing my first array and not the second:

```
# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_raid
OK: cciss:[/dev/cciss/c0d0: (Smart Array E200i) RAID 1 Volume 0 status: OK, /dev/cciss/c0d0: (Smart Array E200i) RAID 1 Volume 1 status: OK]
```

`cciss_vol_status` reports correctly for both arrays:

```
# cciss_vol_status /dev/cciss/c0d0
/dev/cciss/c0d0: (Smart Array E200i) RAID 1 Volume 0 status: OK. 
/dev/cciss/c0d0: (Smart Array E200i) RAID 1 Volume 1 status: OK. 
# cciss_vol_status /dev/cciss/c0d1
/dev/cciss/c0d1: (Smart Array E200i) RAID 1 Volume 0 status: OK. 
/dev/cciss/c0d1: (Smart Array E200i) RAID 1 Volume 1 status: OK.
```

How do I get `check_raid` to report on both arrays?

The server is an HP Proliant DL360 G5 with a Smart Array E200i controller. It's currently running debian wheezy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the [HP Management and Health Agents](http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/project/mcp/) for the server. Those can email, dump to syslog and send SNMP traps.

If you *absolutely* must have this reported in Nagios, it seems like there are [plenty of options](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/HP-(Compaq)). But a component of the HP set of tools is the `hpssacli` or `hpacucli` utility, whose output could be parsed:

```
# hpssacli ctrl all show config

Smart Array P420i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 001438025AC2EA0)

   Internal Drive Cage at Port 1I, Box 2, OK

   Internal Drive Cage at Port 2I, Box 0, OK
   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 340650  MB)

      logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, RAID 1, OK)
      logicaldrive 2 (600.0 GB, RAID 1, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:2:1 (port 1I:box 2:bay 1, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:2:2 (port 1I:box 2:bay 2, SAS, 900.1 GB, OK)

   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380  (WWID: 5001438025AC2EAF)
```

or

```
# hpssacli ctrl slot=0 ld 1 show status

   logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, 1): OK

# hpssacli ctrl slot=0 ld 2 show status

   logicaldrive 2 (600.0 GB, 1): OK
```

or maybe:

```
# hpssacli ctrl all show config | grep logicaldrive
      logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, RAID 1, OK)
      logicaldrive 2 (600.0 GB, RAID 1, OK)
```

Comment: I had a feeling I would get an answer from you :) . That worked great, I installed `hpacucli`, uninstalled `cciss-vol-status` and the `check_raid` plugin is now working for both arrays. Thanks!